# Self-Achievements and society-focused-achievements

Tags: word-request

Is there any English terms that describe:

1. Achievements that are centered about yourself like; money, car, etc. where it does not necessarily mean selfishness but rather achievements that the majority would like to have.
2. Achievements that are directed toward the society like; helping disabled people, doing charity, etc without expecting something in return?

I am thinking about self-achievements and society-focused-achievements but I need more eloquent and professional terms for my statement of purpose.

Comment: Are you looking for one term that can describe both? Or two terms that describe and differentiate between the two concepts?

Comment: @J.R. two terms that describe and differentiate between the two concepts something like "self-achievements and society-focused-achievements "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to find more common adjectives that could be used in such expressions, I'd use ***individual*** **achievements** and ***social*** **achievements**.

Achievements *can* be made on behalf of individuals other than yourself, but when this is done repeatedly the number of people who benefit end up being considered as part of a social environment.

Comment: I think we could use _accomplishments_, too. Good adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

For 2., the adjective [altruistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altruistic) works:

> having or showing an unselfish concern for the welfare of others

<sub>(source: Merriam-Webster)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

For 1: I'd use **Esteem** or **Self-actualization**.

> Esteem: having qualities such as self- respect, confidence, competence, achievement and freedom and it also include recognition, power, status, attention and admiration ( any form of promoting self-respect and admiration).
>
> Self-actualization: is growth and self-contentment. It also includes the desire for gaining more knowledge, social- service, creativity and being aesthetic.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: ok @NathanTuggy